# How to get 2nd partial derivative of a function of two vector variables

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

I am having trouble to calculate the expression:
$$
\textbf{C}_{\textbf{q s}}\ \dot{\textbf{q}}\ \dot{\textbf{s}} = \frac{\partial^2 \textbf{C}}{\partial \textbf{q} \partial \textbf{s}}\ \dot{\textbf{q}} \ \dot{\textbf{s}} 
$$
where $\textbf{C}$ is:

$
\textbf{C}\left(\textbf{q}\left(t\right),\ \textbf{s}\left(t\right)\right) = \textbf{R}^i\left(q_1,\ q_2\right)+\textbf{A}^i\left(q_3\right) \textbf{u}^i \left(s_1\right)- \textbf{R}^j\left(q_4,\ q_5\right)+\textbf{A}^j\left(q_6\right) \textbf{u}^j\left(s_2\right)
$

and

$
\textbf{q} = \left[q_1\dots q_6\right]^T\\
\textbf{s} = \left[s_1,\ s_2\right]^T\\
\dot{\textbf{q}} - \text{vector of first time derivative respect to time}
\\
\dot{\textbf{s}} - \text{vector of first time derivative respect to time}
$

I have managed to calculate the first partial derivative of $\textbf{C}$ with respect to $\textbf{q}$ (that is $\textbf{C}_{\textbf{q}}$ - a matrix 2 by 6) and with respect to $\textbf{s}$ (that is $\textbf{C}_{\textbf{s}}$ - a matrix 2 by 2).

I am having trouble of calculating this second partial mixed derivative as the vectors $\text{q}$ and $\textbf{s}$ have different size and I do not understand what should be the matrix $\textbf{C}_{qs}$ size (shape) and how to calculate each element. Any suggestions what to look for?

Comment: The most practical way would be to introduce a new dimension, i.e. a new index. So instead of a matrix, you would be getting a 3rd order tensor.

Comment: So it would be a 2x6x2 tensor, assuming you add indices "at the back".

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks for the idea. I am not sure how would I then multiply this tensor 2x6x2 with vectors $\dot{\textbf{q}}$ 1x6 and $\dot{\textbf{s}}$ 1x2?

Comment: I don't know what the expressions are supposed to mean. Do you have any background?

Comment: The two vectors $\dot{\textbf{q}}$ and $\dot{\textbf{s}}$ are written in first equation, they are the time derivatives of vectors $\textbf{q}$ and $\textbf{s}$ as it is also written in the main question below. Do you need some additional background (info)? Please say...

Comment: Would need more context from the literature of what the expression is supposed to mean. Is it multiplication, and if so, then how?

Comment: @mathreadler The base is a [book](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12580896/Railroad%20Vehicle%20Dynamics%20-%20A%20Computational%20Approach.pdf), more precisely Eq. 6.25. I have derived some steps of how to get this equation [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12580896/2015-04-30%2013.32.39.jpg). Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a second time derivative of $\bf C$. Is there any interpretation what your expression would mean? I don't see any such expression anywhere near 6.25.

Comment: Correct,it is a second time derivative of $\textbf{C}$. To get this 2nd time derivative of $\textbf{C}$ I've to calculate all the terms inside a frame - marked in my writting paper. The goal is to get the Eq.6.26-an expression for $\textbf{Q}_d$ and this is based on Eq.6.25.The expression $\textbf{C}_{qs}$ one gets if one calculates the 2nd time derivative of $\textbf{C}$ and Eq.6.25 is the final form without intermediate steps, if I am right? Physical meaning is just terms that are quadratic in velocities, i.e. where you multiply with square of velocity.

Comment: What does "square" of velocity even mean? Velocity is a vector quantity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23400/discussion-between-avstenit-and-mathreadler).